# Indeterminacy locus of an Iitaka fibration

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

This might be a trivial question, in this case I apologize. Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex algebraic variety of dimension $n$ and Kodaira dimension $n-1$. Let $\phi:X\dashrightarrow Z$ be the Iitaka fibration, i.e. the rational map induced by the linear system $|mK_X|$ for $m$ divisible enough. When $n=2$ then the indeterminacy locus of $\phi$ is a divisor, hence after extending $\phi$ in codimension one we obtain a legit morphism to $Z$. Does the same hold in general?

Comment: @Doesbaddel dashed right arrow is also an idiomatic notation for rational maps in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't know.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by "extending $\phi$ in codimension one"?

Comment: @NickL The divisor $mK_X$ is linearly equivalent to $M+F$ where $M$ is the mobile part of the linear series $|mK_X|$ and $F$ is the fixed divisor. The extension of $\phi$ in codimension one is the rational map given by $|M|$